# Transforming / stretching map or it's part in particular direction

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, affine-transformation, stretch

I am trying to model ancient land surfaces we can 'rollback' geological folding and faulting. This is called palinspastic modelling or mapping.

So I have an area that due to folding and faulting was reduced by 50% in a N-S direction. I am using QGIS.

I have been unable to find any preset function that will allow me to stretch my map by 150% in the NS direction.

I did look at creating a custom CRS but even within proj and WKT there does not appear to be this facility. I am sure there must be and I have missed it.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

GRASS library [v.transform](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.transform.html) did the work.

I tried it on the QGIS 3.11.0 with GRASS 7.8.2 version and I got no response.

Reverting to version 3.10.1 with GRASS 7.8.0 the transformation worked fine. Possibly an issue with my installation.